# Fluent UI DetailList MultiSelect click on row

Tags: reactjs, listview, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

So, my problem is, I want to have a DetailList component with multi select. Easy enough in documentation it's just what I need.
My code is almost identical except of content, so I pasted example from documentation.
But in the given example bellow, multi select only works if you click ok radio buttons on the left. If you click on the row, only one gets selected, which is not user friendly.

My question is how to make it behave same, regardless if you click on row or on radio button ? In both cases I want multi select.

Link to example and documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/basic

I've looked over the web for solution quite a lot, but haven't found one.

Comment: My guess is that is by design.  If you 'shift-click' on the rows, they can be multi-selected.

Comment: Possibly, but that is not acceptable, because average user wouldn't know this.